# CSS3 animations and updating the DOM

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm new to CSS3 transitions and wondering if this is possible.

Lets say I have a div with 2 child divs in it, like so:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="apple">Apple</div>
    <div id="orange">Orange</div>
</div>
```

My goal is that when I add a new div in between the apple and orange divs, I'd like it to animate the two divs to slide apart and the new div would enter in.

I'm not so concerned about figuring out how to do the CSS3 transitions, but my question is whether this is possible if the entire container div is replaced in the dom.

So due to our design our AJAX response doesn't reply with just a new div to go in the container. Instead it returns the entire div container again, but including the new div in the center, such as:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="apple">Apple</div>
    <div id="banana">Banana</div>
    <div id="orange">Orange</div>
</div>
```

Is this possible to animate something like this when the elements animating are being replaced? Is this more of a jQuery task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely have to replace the whole div container, I don't think there is any way to get the desired translation effect you want. You could do some kind of fade transition where the old fades out as the new fades in.

Answer (score 0):

Look at CSS3 animation with keyframes. It's webkit and firefox only of course.

Answer (score 0):

Adam, what would be easier is to have the div already there in the html, and just set its css to

```
display: none; opacity: 0;
```

by default. Once the action that you want occurs, you can use a css transition on the position of the divs to slide them up nicely and have an opacity transition on the banana div to make it fade in. I could make you a jsfiddle if you told me that you want the divs to come in upon a click on a button.